# Do I need to synchronize items in a CopyOnWriteArrayList if they are updated and read by different threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

If I share a list of items between threads using a CopyOnWriteArrayList do I further need to synchronize the items if they are updated and read by different threads?

Currently my item class definition is below. Do I need to add synchronized to each getter and setter?

Basically I want to make sure changes by one thread are visible in another thread - i think the CopyOnWriteArrayList will provide a memory barrier to ensure this but i want to be sure - thanks

```
public class MyClass {
    private String string;
    private Long longObj;
    private long longprim;

    public String getString() {
        return string;
    }

    public void setString(String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }

    public Long getLongObj() {
        return longObj;
    }

    public void setLongObj(Long longObj) {
        this.longObj = longObj;
    }

    public long getLongprim() {
        return longprim;
    }

    public void setLongprim(long longprim) {
        this.longprim = longprim;
    }
}
```

Comment: You instance of `CopyOnWriteArrayList` will probably be fine, but instances of your `MyClass` will not if modified concurrently.

Comment: you need to sync the CopyOnWrite operation only

Comment: What are you asking? The `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is thread safe. You can use it with multiple threads just fine. It's very slow if `add` is common - `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` is much faster in this case. `MyClass` is not thread safe and if you are mutating them with multiple threads then the usually visibility and atomicity caveats apply, just the same as if you were sharing a single instance between multiple threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `CopyOnWriteArrayList` contains mutable items you need full synchronization for item class. Imagine, two threads access the same item within the list (safe list operations) and then manipulate this item (unsafe).